# Powering Sim808 + Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno

I am currently making a GPS tracker with UNO and SIM808 ([this is the model](https://www.lelong.com.my/sim808-module-gsm-gprs-gps-development-board-arduino-stelectronics-191687273-2018-04-Sale-P.htm).

It says `The range of voltage of Lithium battery input power is 3.5 - 4.2V.` for the module. I am aware that UNO needs 5V to power.

I want to make it compact as possible so it can be placed within the dashboard of a car or motorcycle.

How do I power both of this using just one battery holder?

Comment: Use an Arduino running at 8MHz - it can then run with anywhere from 2.8V to 5.5V reliably.

Comment: Can UNO running at 8MHz? Or should I buy another arduino? I heard there is a dissadvantage of running at 8MHz, which is slower. Do you have any links for the solid answer? I have been googling arround, but did not find the solid one. All discussions makes me confused.

Comment: No, buy a 3.3v pro mini. The only disadvantage of running slower is you are running slower.

Comment: One more thing, if I burn bootloader on UNO to 8 MHz and using 3.7v and 2A battery, will it damage the UNO? Because UNO can only hold 20 or 40 mA. If you put the answer, I will mark it

Comment: You will need to make hardware modifications for 8MHz. I.e., change the resonator for an 8MHz one.  And what do you mean the Arduino can only hold 20mA? That makes no sense whatsoever.